# Curious results from pg_stat_user_indexes

Tags: postgresql, index, postgis, gist-index

**PostgreSQL 12.8, PostGIS 3.1.4**

Running `select * from pg_stat_user_indexes`, there are some rows that have 0 for `idx_scan`, and a >0 result for `idx_tup_read`.

The indexes that match this condition are all simple SP-Gist indexes, i.e.,

```
CREATE INDEX ... USING spgist(geometry)
```

The definition for `idx_tup_read` is "Number of index entries returned by scans on this index."

If `idx_scan` is 0, I would expect "scans on this index" to be 0 as well. So how can `idx_tup_read` have a result greater than 0, if `idx_scan` is 0?

Comment: I don't see any likely explanations for this.  I was thinking of get_actual_variable_range() when used in planning merge joins, but I see that this *does* increment idx_scan, and also probably doesn't make sense for spgist anyway.  What kinds of queries do you run that involve those columns?  What lead you to create those indexes in the first place?

Comment: @jjanes a number of queries involve the geom column, the only ones i would expect to use the index are a variety of different ST_Intersect-based queries. The sp-gist index was created as a test to compare to standard gist performance. However, it likely should not have been left around - I am in the process of eliminating excess indexes from these tables.